# How to sync answer/question draft between the mobile app and the web site?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, draft, web

Sometimes I find myself start writing a question, or start answering a question, in the mobile app and there are times where I then reach my computer or find out I need to be more comfortable when writing it; I need my computer - a larger screen, keyboard.

The problem is that by opening the question in the *desktop* browser - my draft will not be there and so I find myself start over or need to look&copy my text from the smartphone or email it, etc. Not particularly comfortable...

I think we need some sort of a syncing ability.

Comment: The server already saves drafts made through the website. This could just be an extension of that.

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats the apps (both iOS and android) are now frozen, their development is on hold for unlimited time. So this feature won't ever happen.

Comment: Oh really? That’s a shame... I wonder why the tree was put in place.