# Draft feature on PC

Tags: support, draft

On my phone, I can make drafts for questions.  However, upon returning home, I wanted to complete my draft, but cannot find any drafts button on my PC.  Is this a bug?

Comment: So, are you asking if it's a bug or are you asking for this to be a feature on the site? Your tagging doesn't match your question. The info on how drafts work is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/284336.

Comment: If the duplicate linked above doesn't answer your question, chime in back here so we can try to clarify what problem you might be seeing.

Comment: @RobertCartaino if I understand the point of the question, it's asking whether it's possible to transfer a draft on your phone to a desktop... which it is not. They are saved using cookies on the PC and aren't otherwise attached to your account, only to the system you're on... which means that even switching between two desktops will not retain the draft. These things don't seem to be directly addressed in the duplicate, particularly not any information about the app that I can see, which does it in a slightly different manner.

Comment: If you're talking about the iOS version of the app, there's some information here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220705/maintain-local-draft-in-ios-app And for android here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193005/allow-me-to-draft-a-question-in-the-stack-exchange-android-app This is also pretty much an exact duplicate of this question, which doesn't have an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248503/how-to-sync-answer-question-draft-between-the-mobile-app-and-the-web-site though this is actually a FR.

Comment: I am sorry.  The post does not answer my question. I am looking for the draft button on stack exchange on computer

Comment: Can anyone answer my question here?

Comment: @XcoderX sure, such feature does not exist. Closed as dupe of similar feature request.